# My distinct digits program doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, digits, distinct-values

I'm making a program that will add +1 to a year each time the program checks that it's not a distinct digit, until it is one. I have no idea why it's not working, any help would be appreciated. it was working yesterday when I got home, but today it just doesn't want to work.

```csharp
        private void yearInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) // Year Input Textbox \\
        {

        }

        public bool exception;
        public static int yearInputInt;
        public static strng yearInputString;

        private void yearInputConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Year Input Confirm Button \\
        {
            exception = false;
            yearInputString = yearInput.Text;
            yearInputInt = Int32.Parse(yearInputString);
            if (yearInputString.Length == 2)
            {
                while (yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(1, 1))
                {
                    yearInputInt = yearInputInt + 1;
                    yearInputString = yearInputInt.ToString();
                    if (yearInputString.Length == 3)
                    {
                        while (yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1))
                        {
                            yearInputInt = yearInputInt + 1;
                            yearInputString = yearInputInt.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (yearInputString.Length == 3)
            {
                while (yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1))
                {
                    yearInputInt = yearInputInt + 1;
                    yearInputString = yearInputInt.ToString();
                    if (yearInputString.Length == 4)
                    {
                        while (yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1))
                        {
                            yearInputInt = yearInputInt + 1;
                            yearInputString = yearInputInt.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (yearInputString.Length == 4)
            {
                while (yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) == yearInputString.Substring (2, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1))
                {
                    yearInputInt = yearInputInt + 1;
                    yearInputString = yearInputInt.ToString();
                    if (yearInputString.Length == 5)
                    {
                        while (yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(4, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(4, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(4, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(4, 1))
                        {
                            yearInputInt = yearInputInt + 1;
                            yearInputString = yearInputInt.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (yearInputString.Length == 5)
            {
                while (yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(0, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(4, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(1, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(4, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(2, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(4, 1) || yearInputString.Substring(3, 1) == yearInputString.Substring(4, 1))
                {
                    yearInputInt = yearInputInt + 1;
                    yearInputString = yearInputInt.ToString();
                }
            }
            label2.Text = yearInputString;
        }
```

When I compile in Visual Studio, the compiling process just crashes and get the error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: distinctDigitsRev, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 
1>H:\profile\desktop\C#\distinctDigitsRevamped\distinctDigitsRev\distinctDigitsR‌​ev\Form1.cs(28,23,28,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'strng' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== –
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get any error?

Comment: I assume there are some errors shown which might help to understand the reason of the crash, could you post it as well?

Comment: Have a look to my answer. P.s.not sure that Visual Studio is the best IDE for Java, try Intellij IDEA, this will show you all the hints straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 8, string is spelled wrong.

```
 public static strng yearInputString;
```

---

The line should be:

```
 public static string yearInputString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of the variable *yearInputString*. Notice that you are missing *i* from *string*.